# How to force Play framework 2 to always use SSL?

Tags: scala, ssl, heroku, playframework-2.0

I have a Play Framework app running on Heroku, using Heroku's SSL endpoint.

I would like to make all pages available via `SSL` only.

**What's the best way to that?**

So far, my best solution is to use `onRouteRequest` in my `GlobalSettings` and route `non-SSL` requests to a special redirect handler:

```
override def onRouteRequest(request: RequestHeader): Option[Handler] = {
  if (Play.isProd && !request.headers.get("x-forwarded-proto").getOrElse("").contains("https")) {
    Some(controllers.Secure.redirect)
  } else {
    super.onRouteRequest(request)
  }
}
```

and

```
package controllers

import play.api.mvc._

object Secure extends Controller {

  def redirect = Action { implicit request =>
    MovedPermanently("https://" + request.host + request.uri)
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do this entirely from within `GlobalSettings`? Or something even better?

Comment: You can turn off non-ssl by starting with -Dhttp.port=disabled if that's what you're looking for: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ConfiguringHttps

Comment: From Play's point of view, I'm not using SSL. Heroku's load balancer is proxying the SSL to straight HTTP for the app.

Comment: was there any update on this? I ended up doing something similar but I would've preffered the disabled http but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have done that much like you but with a play filter that generates a MovedPermanently instead of a controller method.

I don't think there is a better way with heroku, or at least we couldn't find any feature to disable unencrypted HTTP.

Comment: How do you force a redirect from a filter?

Comment: Just return a Result (or Future[SimpleResult] in play 2.2) instead of invoking the next action/essentialaction

Answer (score 12):

Here is another way using filter.  This also uses strict transport security to make sure that future requests go to https.

```
object HTTPSRedirectFilter extends Filter with Logging {

    def apply(nextFilter: (RequestHeader) => Future[SimpleResult])(requestHeader: RequestHeader): Future[SimpleResult] = {
        //play uses lower case headers.
        requestHeader.headers.get("x-forwarded-proto") match {
            case Some(header) => {
                if ("https" == header) {
                    nextFilter(requestHeader).map { result =>
                        result.withHeaders(("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=31536000"))
                    }
                } else {
                    Future.successful(Results.Redirect("https://" + requestHeader.host + requestHeader.uri, 301))
                }
            }
            case None => nextFilter(requestHeader)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you add the `result.withHeaders(("Strict-Transport-Security", "max-age=31536000"))`? Is this a mandatory header?

Comment: You can read about it more on [my blog](http://www.mentful.com/2014/05/25/play-framework-filter-for-aws-elastic-load-balancer-forward-http-to-https/)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution for the Java version of Play Framework.

Add the following to the Global.java file:

```
@Override
public Handler onRouteRequest(RequestHeader request) {
    String[] x = request.headers().get("X-Forwarded-Proto");
    if (Play.isProd() && (x == null || x.length == 0 || x[0] == null || !x[0].contains("https")))
        return controllers.Default.redirect("https://" + request.host() + request.uri());
    return super.onRouteRequest(request);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly, I am not getting anything in X-Forwarded-Proto. Probably due to the front HTTP server setup.

Comment: This cannot work as controllers.Default.redirect() is a non-static method.

Answer (score 2):

In Play 2.5.x Java (I think should work in play 2.4.x as well but using `Promise.F` instead of `CompletionStage`), I added a filter:

```
public class TLSFilter extends Filter {
    @Inject
    public TLSFilter(Materializer mat) {
        super(mat);
    }

    @Override
    public CompletionStage<Result> apply(Function<Http.RequestHeader, CompletionStage<Result>> next, Http.RequestHeader rh) {
        if (Play.current().isProd()) {
            String[] httpsHeader = rh.headers().getOrDefault(Http.HeaderNames.X_FORWARDED_PROTO, new String[]{"http"});
            if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(httpsHeader[0]) || httpsHeader[0].equalsIgnoreCase("http")) {
                return CompletableFuture.completedFuture(Results.movedPermanently("https://".concat(rh.host().concat(rh.uri()))));
            }
        }
        return next.apply(rh).toCompletableFuture();
    }
}
```

And then add it to the list of filters to use it:

```
public class AppFilters extends DefaultHttpFilters {

    @Inject
    public AppFilters(TLSFilter tlsFilter, GzipFilter gzipFilter) {
        super(tlsFilter, gzipFilter);
    }
}
```

And then to use your filters add the following inside `application.conf` :

```
play.http.filters = "filters.AppFilters"
```

And please note, if you have a request handler enabled (look for `play.http.requestHandler` inside the `application.conf` file), filters will not work, I suggest to handle requests using filters and remove your current requestHandler.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement using Play 2.2.3. I'm running my application behind a load balancer which is doing the SSL termination, and wanted all HTTP requests to be redirected to SSL. In my case, my load balancer (Amazon ELB) adds the X-Forwarded-Proto header, so I keyed off it as follows. In Global.java (or whatever class you've got that extends GlobalSettings), add this method:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
@Override
public Action onRequest(Request actionRequest, Method actionMethod) {

  String forwardedProtocol = actionRequest.getHeader("X-Forwarded-Proto");

  if (StringUtils.equalsIgnoreCase(forwardedProtocol, "http")) {

    // Redirect to HTTPS
    final String secureURL = "https://" + actionRequest.host() + actionRequest.uri();
    return new Action.Simple() {
      @Override
      public Promise<play.mvc.SimpleResult> call(Context ctx) throws Throwable {
        return Promise.pure(Results.movedPermanently(secureURL));
      }
    };

  } else {

    return super.onRequest(actionRequest, actionMethod);

  }
}
```

This doesn't handle custom ports, so some might implementations might require a little extra coding.